# flutter Custompaint inside listview : ignore two fingers scroll

Tags: flutter, listview, gesture

I have a stack with custompaint inside a listview. The problem is sometimes I can't draw because the listView is intercepting the gesture with one finger (which is use by the custompaint) and I get a vertical scrolling…

How ignore two fingers scroll?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is that use **behaviour** attribute in `GestureDetector()` and setting `ListView()`'s **physics** to `PageScrollPhysics()` could do the trick.

**behaviour** takes values `HitTestBehavior.opaque`, `HitTestBehavior.deferToChild` and `HitTestBehavior.translucent`.

Comment: Thanks for your  comment. But there is a problem with GestureDetector. It produce Junck when you draw on CustomPaint inside a scroll Widget like ListView, and is too slow to detect move on CustomPaint before the listView get focus. The solution is to replace the GestureDetector by a Listener more efficient.